# Feeling stuck after relocating. Considering changing "specs"

Tags: resume, united-states, united-kingdom, careers

I got my Bsc in CS from Polytechnic Univ. of Bucharest in 2014. I moved to London in February, this year. I have been struggling to get a job since. My experience with C++ consists of an year and in VoIP and CAD applications. In terms of C++, I only have experience with STL, no QT, no Boost.

Aside of that, I've been learning, more like a passion/hobby about js and Node.js.

I have applied to over 200 jobs, mainly targeting new grad or junior roles, got about 10 answers back, never heard after interview. Successfully interviewed with most of major US tech companies(1 to 1 apply to interview rate), never managed to pass the technical interview.

Should I switch from C++ to js/Node.js ? 
Why am I getting stuck? How to move out of it? Start a personal project? Which would be the most impactful way to boost my skill/relevance?

Comment: "never managed to pass the technical interview" <-- why not? Surely this would be a strong indicator ... ?

Comment: One massive thing missing is contact information on your resume. Cover letter and resume often get seporated. You need all your contact info on your resume. address/e-mail/phone   Links are good for online versions but resumes get printed and passed around by hand. So you need to make sure the links are still usable (short). Three pages is too long. Two pages max but if this is your first job then one page should be enough.

Comment: I removed the contact details as they weren't relevant to the question. As  for interviews. I'm not sure how not passing a Google interview justifies not find a job.

Comment: You question implies multiple interviews with multiple "major US tech companies" (since 'companies' is a plural and 'most' requires more than one), and that you didn't manage to pass any of these. It may help to clarify your question if this is not the case and you only interviewed with one 'major US tech company'.

Comment: Over 200 jobs? What positions were you seeking and not ever getting responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salut, Andrei.

It could be that C++ is not in demand in your area, or it could be that you are not successfully conveying your knowledge and experience (aka you need to work on your résumé). Since you've applied to so many positions without any response I strongly suspect this to be the case. (I'm at work and can't check out your link, however it's not my opinion you need anyway - it's that of an expert in your area)

Din pacate este de asemenea posibil ca multi nu vor sa angajeze straini .. mai ales Romani (inteleg ca nu avem reputatie prea buna pe acolo).

If you are proficient in Node.js you should definitely put this information on your résumé! It's a hugely valuable asset to have, and you should be very employable if you know what you're doing.

Javascript - in particular Node and Angular - are the fastest growing technologies on the market, and also the highest paying (check out the Stack Overflow 2016 Developer Survey).

You can also try creating a LinkedIn profile, and building a Github portfolio of personal projects in order to compensate for the lack of official experience using these technologies (Node).

Mult succes, si nu te da batut!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but looking at your résumé, it's 3 pages long, covers 3 years.
It's seems "overreaching".

Shorten your résumé to a single page, highlight your strengths.

Any 'newer' technology you master (but you have to be proficient at it), mention it.
If you like doing it, mention it.

If you just can 'pass' it, or especially if you hate it, don't list it, at least nowhere prominent.

As for completely switching, depending on the hiring place, make sure you change your résumé to focus on what you'd like to do there.

Good luck.